# Incorrect rounding

Tags: php, rounding

I am writing some PHP code which is intended to display times as '1 min', '2 mins', '3 hours' etc based on a time stored in a mysql table, and comparing to the current time. My current code is as follows:

```
    $dif = (strtotime("-0 minutes") - strtotime($time))/60;
    if($dif < 1){
        return "Just Now";
    }elseif($dif < 2){
        return round($dif, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN) . " Min";
    }elseif($dif < 60){
        return round($dif, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN) . " Mins";
    }elseif($dif/60 < 2){
        return round($dif/60, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN) . " Hour";
    }elseif($dif/60 < 24){
        return round($dif/60, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN) . " Hours";
    }elseif($dif/1440 < 2){
        return round($dif/1440, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN) . " Day";
    }elseif($dif/1440 < 4){
        return round($dif/1440, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN) . " Days";
    }else{
        $datepieces = explode(" ", $time);
        $date = date("j F, Y", strtotime($datepieces[0]));
        return $date;
    }
```

My issue however is that when the timer switches from '1 Min' to '2 Mins', for a period of around 30 seconds '2 Min' is returned. Can anyone assist in spotting a mistake I have made in rounding which would cause this to happen?

Comment: Does this have anything to do with mysql?

Comment: `2 Min` will be returned for any time with `$dif` value of `1.50 - 1.99`. Do you expect something different?

Comment: Gordon Linoff - I should have mentioned, the incoming date/time format is mysql, not sure how relevant this is, however I thought this could contribute to the data being passed.

Comment: Set Sail Media - I intended for 1.5 or 1.99 to be rounded down to '1', so that the correct non-plural ending was used. Perhaps incorrect rounding code?

Answer (score 0):

Try `floor` instead?

```
$dif = (strtotime("-0 minutes") - strtotime($time))/60;
if($dif < 1){
    return "Just Now";
}elseif($dif < 2){
    return floor($dif) . " Min";
}elseif($dif < 60){
    return floor($dif) . " Mins";
}elseif($dif/60 < 2){
    return floor($dif/60) . " Hour";
}elseif($dif/60 < 24){
    return floor($dif/60) . " Hours";
}elseif($dif/1440 < 2){
    return floor($dif/1440) . " Day";
}elseif($dif/1440 < 4){
    return floor($dif/1440) . " Days";
}else{
    $datepieces = explode(" ", $time);
    $date = date("j F, Y", strtotime($datepieces[0]));
    return $date;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I still get '2 min' with this code however.